# How to repair Windows 8.1?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

I **currently have no OS installed on my PC** but **my laptop came pre-installed with Windows 8.1**, so there is an image on the hard disk to install Windows 8.1 without the need of USB.

However, when I tried to install Windows 8.1 from that image, I got the error message that the **image was corrupt**, so I need another bootable Windows USB to continue the installation which I don't have (I neither have a bootable Windows DVD or any bootable Windows USB).

So, I went to **Command prompt** from the startup in **Advanced Options** and tried running `sfc /scannow` but it didn't work. I have also tried `chkdsk /f` but they didn't work.

The `sfc /scannow` showed that there were some errors that need to be fixed, however it couldn't fix them for the reason that I am running the command from that partition itself.

It said something like **The Windows cannot repair the partition**.

**How to fix the factory image corrupt error using the command prompt?**

Comment: IMHO it is easier to download a Win8.1 image, create a bootable USB stick with it and install from scratch as trying to "fix the factory image corrupt error using the command prompt"

Comment: @duDE I don't have a USB with capacity to store the ISO file.

Comment: So buy some, it's about 5$ meantime.

Comment: the easiest would be to [download the image from microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/), format your complete drive and reinstall your OS with or without USB/DVD...

Comment: @DJCrashdummy how? Where should I boot that ISO from?

Comment: from any DVD-drive, usb-stick or any other usb-storage (e.g. a sd-card with a usb-card-reader) or probably your pc can boot from it's internal card-reader...

Comment: @DJCrashdummy I don't currently have any one of them. Can I boot it from the internal harddisk partition itself i.e. by creating a partition in the hard disk and mounting the iso file there.

Comment: well the easiest would be to buy one of them... even a re-writeable DVD coasts less then one $/€/£. -- and if you don't want to buy any oft them (which i won't do either), ask a friend to borrow one (**empty**) of them for a quick one-time usage.

Comment: If the image is corrupt then the only solution is to download a Windows 8.1 ISO and use the image contained on that.  "It said something like" - Edit your question to include the exact error message you recieved.  You should be using the tool, DISM, instead of sfc to repair your installation.  You can within WinRE mount an external .wim image, point the tool to an offline installation, and repair the installation.

Comment: @Ramhound Can I overwrite data in that partition with ISO image that is downloaded?

Comment: Just use the WinRE and DISM resolution.